# Why is $f_L$ continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

When I read the paper “Hillel Gauchman, Pinching theorems for totally real minimal sub manifolds of $\mathbb{C}P^n(c)$”, I don't understand why the following function **$f_L$ is continuous**?

> Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $L$ be a $(0,k)$-tensor field on $M$. At any $x\in M$, $L$ can be considered as a multilinear map $L:T_xM\times \cdots \times T_xM\to \mathbb R$. Let $UM$ be the unit tangent bundle of $M$ and $UM_x$ its fiber at $x\in M$. We say that $u \in UM_x$ is a maximal direction at $x$ with respect to $L$, if it satisfies $L(u,\cdots ,u)=\max_{v\in UM_x}L(v,\cdots ,v)$. For any $x\in M$, set $f_L(x)=L(u,\cdots ,u)$, where $u$ is a maximal direction at $x$ with respect to $L$.

Perhaps this is similar to another question, namely, is the maximum value of the section curvature at each point on the Riemannian manifold a continuous function?

Answer (score 2):

If you trivialize $TM$ near $x\in M$, you have a family of functions on $S^{n-1}$, namely $g_x:S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $g_x(v)=L(v,...,v)$ and want to show that the min value of $g_x$ is continuous in $x$. This is covered [here](https://williewong.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/continuity-of-the-infimum/).

Comment: Thank you. I see. Another question is, are there examples where $f_L$ is just a continuous function and not a smooth function?

Comment: Sure. Take M to be a circle, locally R.  Let L(v, x)=vx locally in M, in a trivialization (this is linear in v). Then f_L is |x|.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you!